# MongoOperations - upsert/findAndModify deleting all the fields in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to user MongoOperarions, and the method upsert to only update/create those fields that are present in the update parameter. But, whenever I send in an empty list of fields to be update, it deletes all the other fields in the database, being the only one remaining the "I'd" field
Are you guys aware of a way to avoid having to do this? Ideally, I would expect it to just tell me that nothing was done, instead of deleting everything.

**EDIT 1**

This is what my code looks like:

```
Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
        final Update update = new Update();
        fields.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(entry->{
                    if(entry.getValue()!=null)
                        update.set(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
                });

        return mongoOperation.findAndModify(query,update,Destination.class);
```

As you can see, I'm using `$set` operation for the update. What happens in my scenario, is that the update variable has no pair field-value to be updated, and it ends up deleting everything under the given id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to filter out any calls that had no fields to update before getting to the update comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$set` for this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

So if you have a document with a `user id`, `name` and `age` for example, then the following would replace the whole document and you'd lose age:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'new name'
}
```

But using `$set` will update or add just the fields from the query, so the age field wouldn't be lost

```
{
    '$set': {
        id: 1,
        name: 'new name'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I'm using set, this is what my code looks like:

'fields.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(entry->{
                    if(entry.getValue()!=null)
                        update.set(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
                });'

Comment: Ah right, I get you. What that means then is when you get to the `findAndModify`, you're effectively running an update like this:
```
db.collection.findAndModify({
 query: { "id": <id> },
 update: {}
})
```
so no `$set`, which does wipe out the whole document, leaving just the key.

I'm not that familiar with Spring unfortunately, but is it possible to compare the update object before and after the loop to see if it's been modified? `equals` or `hashCode` maybe? Or use your own mechanism in the loop to check if set was called?